# rvest package scrape td with class issue

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I am new for rvest package and I would like to scrape a html but unable to do it.

I would like to scrape the value 10.360 in td class "ng-binding".

```
code:
url <- "http://stock360.hkej.com/quotePlus/1212"
stk <- read_html(url)
x <- html_nodes(stk, "td.ng-binding")
html_text(x)

Result:
{xml_nodeset (0)}

outer html:
<td class="ng-binding">10.360</td>

xpath:
 /html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/
 table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

I tried to use html_nodes(stk, "td") but can't find the value. please advise. Thank you.

Comment: That's b/c it's loaded via http://stock360.hkej.com/data/getQuotes/01212?t=1513650393840 dynamically

Comment: so no way to do it in R ?

Comment: There is definitely a way of doing it in R and plenty of q's on SO to help you mine XHR requests. I just don't answer most finance or sports/gambling scraping questions anymore.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help